# Reduce quality of image for faster surf algorithm opencv Android

Tags: java, android, c++, image

I am trying to match images with surf algorithm on android. I have a JavaCameraView object which capture image from camera in my java class. I passed this image to my native class like that:

```
      @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        _mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        _mRgba.release();

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
  {
        _mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        nativeClass.detectAndMatch(_mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());

        return _mRgba;
    }
```

But in c++ code surf algorithm is very slow. This is my code:

```
 Mat& frame = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
    Mat grayFrame, desGrayFrame;
    Mat object, desObject;
    vector<KeyPoint> kpObject;
    vector<KeyPoint> kpGrayFrame;
    vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
    vector<DMatch > good_matches;
    float thresholdMatchingNN=0.7;
    unsigned int tresholdGoodMatches = 4;
    int minHess = 3000;
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    object = imread ("/sdcard/NoTouch/elli.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if(! object.data )
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", "Can not 
        load image from phone");

   }
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHess);
    detector.detect(object, kpObject);
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    extractor.compute(object, kpObject, desObject);
    cvtColor(frame, grayFrame, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    detector.detect(grayFrame, kpGrayFrame);
    extractor.compute(grayFrame, kpGrayFrame, desGrayFrame);
    matcher.knnMatch(desObject, desGrayFrame, matches, 2);
```

I decided to reduce quality of image for faster process like that:

```
Size szSource = new Size(160,120);
_mRgba = new Mat(szSource, CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

it is a little faster but still slow. And I am confused with this code in java:

```
Size szSource = new Size(160,120);
```

Because some of the devices support different resolution. Can you explain clearly how to reduce the quality of the picture? And do you have any other suggestions for speeding up this process ?